# How to check the url is given empty string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi there is there possible to validate the input tag with url type?

I currently have an input tag with URL type for user to key in the url, it is okay if the user key in value that is not a url.

But when user key in "http://www.", my input field accept it and posted the form to the server which is not a proper value. How to check the empty value in the input field to validate empty url?

Here are few scenario my form accepted the url link with empty url:

1. http://www.
2. www.
3. http://

Is there any way to validate and stop the form to submit when there are empty value in the url link with javascript or php? thanks

My FORM's CODE:

```
<form class="form" id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="box-body">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="banner_id" value="1"></input>
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <label for="bannerName">Banner Name 旗帜名称</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bannerName" id="bannerName" placeholder="Please Enter Name" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group" >
                                            <label for="bannerUrl">Banner URL </label>
                                            <input type="url" autocomplete="on" class="form-control" name="bannerUrl" id="bannerUrl" placeholder="Please Enter Url" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);" required>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                                            <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file"  onChange="checkDisabled(testing);"><br>
                                            <p class="help-block">Your picture size not more than 2MB.  (Only JPEG or JPG is allowed)</p>
                                        </div>  

                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Update</button>      
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.box-body -->


                                </form>                  <!-- Date range -->
```

Comment: Follow the approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: If i understood ur question correctly, are you asking for this ?

`<input type='url'>`

Comment: @phpfresher Yes, i'm using <input type ='url'> , but what i wanted to counter is when user enter empty url link like "http://www." , my form should not submit the form. Get it?

Comment: ok i got it... 
Why don't you just check for NULL, 

`if(document.getElementById('field_id').value=="")
{
alert("Please Enter URL");
}`

Comment: @phpfresher your way won't work, it wont check the url value is null or not. Because when i trying to type "http://www." it still can accept my field value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong to understand your question then this will work for you.

Form page

```
<div class="form-group" >
   <label for="bannerUrl">Banner URL </label>
   <input type="url" autocomplete="on" class="form-control" name="bannerUrl" id="bannerUrl" placeholder="Please Enter Url" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);" required>
   <span class="error_label"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery Way**

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules : {
        bannerUrl : {
            required : true,
            url : true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        bannerUrl : {
            required : "This field is required",
            url : "Please enter valid URL"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {  
        if ($(form).valid()) 
            form.submit(); 
            return false; // prevent normal form posting
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {      
        $(element).closest('span').find('.error_label').html(error);
    }
})
```

**Regex Way**

```
$('#bannerUrl').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var checkUrl = checkWebUrl($(this).val());
    console.log(checkUrl);
    if (!checkUrl) {
        // your error message
        alert('Please enter valid url');
        return false;
    } else {
        // your message
        alert('Valid url')
    }
});

function checkWebUrl(url)
{
    //regular expression for URL
    //console.log(learnRegExp('http://www.google-com.123.com')); // true
    //console.log(learnRegExp('http://www.google-com.123')); // false
    //console.log(learnRegExp('https://www.google-com.com')); // true
    //console.log(learnRegExp('http://google-com.com')); // true
    //console.log(learnRegExp('http://google.com')); //true
    //console.log(learnRegExp('google.com')); //false
    //console.log(learnRegExp('www.google')); //false
    //console.log(learnRegExp('http://www.google')); //false
    var urlregex = new RegExp(
        "^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
    return urlregex.test(checkWebUrl.arguments[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hi there actually your code can easily be done with this. <input type"url" required/>

Comment: @MarcusTan I have updated code with regex and simple jquery function to check you can use any of these ways

Comment: How to change after i click submit only check for the url link? Because now everytime i enter one character it check once...

Comment: Its because code is for `on keyup` function you can check that using server side validation

Comment: I currently have a jquery submit function, when your code return false, it still call my submit button. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75253/discussion-between-narendra-sisodia-and-marcus-tan).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery Form Validation. (You can import [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in your application and use it for all your form fields).

```
$('#form').validate({
rules : {
    'bannerUrl' : {
        required : true,
        url : true
    }
},
messages : {
    'bannerUrl' : {
        required : "This field is required",
        url : "Please enter valid URL"
    }
},
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex to validate URL.

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

If the url matches with the above regex then with high probability the given url is valid syntactically. If you don't want such a lengthy and full proof way then you can choose one of the regex from [URL Valid Regex](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex).

If you want to modify the regex based on your requirement, please [test regex](https://www.regex101.com/) and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlexp = new RegExp('(http|ftp|https)://[a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)+([a-z0-9\-\.,@\?^=%&;:/~\+#]*[a-z0-9\-@\?^=%&;/~\+#])?', 'i');
```

Use this regex in javascript, if valid pass the value back to php else post an alert saying error.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the input field value to this function on a if condition it will return true or false

```
    <script>
    function isValidUrl(url) {
         var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?     (\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
         return regexp.test(url);
     }

      isValidUrl(yourURL);
     </script>
```